# libxft-bgra patch for rendering color emoji fonts

Tags: fonts, emoji

Is there any method to install the `libxft-bgra` on ubuntu?. In the AUR they have this "version" of `libxft` which allows you to render color emoji system wide.
I've tried to compile It myself but to get this working I had to remove the standard `libxft` package which removes lots of packages and I don't want to uninstall them. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up patching, compiling, and installing libxft-2.3.3 in prefix /usr/local and then recompiled st, dmenu, and dwm using the library and headers files there instead of the Ubuntu provided versions. This allowed me to keep the Ubuntu versions around.

[Color emojis in dwm bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0clJ.png)

[Color emojis in terminal in Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nahxw.png)

```
st on  master➜ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS \n \l

dwm on  haplo_dwm [$!]➜ ldd /usr/local/bin/st | grep -i xft
        libXft.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libXft.so.2 (0x00007f775d893000)

st on  master [$!]➜ ldd /usr/local/bin/dwm | grep -i xft
        libXft.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libXft.so.2 (0x00007fa4b186a000)

st on  master [$!]➜ ldd /usr/local/bin/dmenu | grep -i xft
        libXft.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libXft.so.2 (0x00007f2ce7bf1000)

st on  master [$!]➜ apt search libxft
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libxft-dev/focal,now 2.3.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
  FreeType-based font drawing library for X (development files)

libxft2/focal,now 2.3.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  FreeType-based font drawing library for X
```

For dwm and dmenu, don't forget to comment out the `iscol` code in `drw.c`  to re-enable color fonts after you have the patch libxft-bgra installed or you won't get color in either of them.

```
/* Do not allow using color fonts. This is a workaround for a BadLength
 * error from Xft with color glyphs. Modelled on the Xterm workaround. See
 * https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1498269
 * https://lists.suckless.org/dev/1701/30932.html
 * https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=916349
 * and lots more all over the internet.
 */
FcBool iscol;
if(FcPatternGetBool(xfont->pattern, FC_COLOR, 0, &iscol) == FcResultMatch && iscol) {
    XftFontClose(drw->dpy, xfont);
    return NULL;
}
```

Let me know if you need any more info.  It went pretty flawlessly for me, and it is definitely nice to have the color emojis in my suckless tools.

Comment: How do you specify to use /usr/local/lib/libXft.so.2 instead of the standard libxft? I mean,do I have to edit the Makefile or another file to point to the compiled one?